# How to read facebook timeline with Graph API?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I need to read facebookk timeline and some tutorial says me to read with API Graph and I use:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/***/posts?access_token=***
```

but when I use this code I obtain  `{data[]}` . I don' know how I wrong. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You question is pretty broad.

Did you use the Facebook API explorer? [Found here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)

Are you sure the token is valid?

I am pretty sure what you are doing wrong is your call above is un-versioned so it will default to v2.0+. Which means you can't query based on user name.  Next if you are using a user Id in the middle *** it will return empty because that user hasn't authorized the app that got the token, and/or has decided to hide themselves from open graph calls. You can use a public page ID in that spot to get that page posts.

Give this a try

`https://graph.facebook.com/ME/posts?access_token=***`

Provided you have a valid token it should work with unversioned calls.  I suggest you play with the API explorer linked above.